# remove a particular color from an image

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, rgb, scikit-image

Is it possible to remove a particular rbg color from an image? For example, I want to create a function such that I pass an image and color as a parameter and it returns the same image but without that color.

For example, this function

**fuction(image, "R")**

should give me an image that has no R shades. How can I do so?

Currently, something like this works:

```
def exclusionWithPIL(image, channel):
    out = None
    image = Image.open(image)
    image_data = image.load()
    height,width = image.size
    for loop1 in range(height):
        for loop2 in range(width):
            r,g,b = image_data[loop1,loop2]
            image_data[loop1,loop2] = 0,g,b
    return image

result = rgb_exclusion('./image.jpg', "G")
result.save('new.jpg')
```

but here, I'm reading the image like this `Image.open(image)` inside the function. Instead, I want to pass in `image1` which is already read like this:

```
image1 = load(image1_path)
```

```
def load(image_path):
    out = io.imread(image_path)
    out = out.astype(np.float64) / 255
    return out
```

How can I modify the function accordingly?
P.S I use io.imread from skimage to read images.

Edit:
if I pass the image loaded by io.imread directly into the function, something like this seems to work:

```
    out = image.copy()
    if (channel == "R"):
        out[:, :, 0] = 0
```

But I don't quite quite understand the indexes `[:, :, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

found a tutorial online which solves exactly your problem:
[Tutorial Link](https://www.codespeedy.com/remove-a-specific-color-from-an-image-in-python/)

The main idea behind their solution is to use PIL in order to open the image, load it, and then iterate over every pixel in the image (using 2 loops) and setting the chosen color to zero.

---

***EDIT:*** I think that your problem occurs because of the fact that you're trying to pass to the function as a parameter an image which was loaded using **sicikit-image** library (`io.imread()`), and then inside the function you're trying to use **PILLOW** library's features on the same image.

That's why it shouldn't work, you're merging between 2 different libraries.
As I see it, there are 2 possible solution:

1. Make the function's parameter the image's path instead of the image itself, and then save the image in the same directory and do not return anything.
2. Stay consistent, and before passing the function an image as a parameter, load it using the **PILLOW** library, and when returning it, refer to the returned image in terms of the **PILLOW** library only.

Comment: In this, we're manipulating the ```image_data```. How can I return the modified image from my function?

Comment: Didn't it work to just use: 'return image', instead of: 'image.save(...)' ?

Comment: Could you see the updated qs? The method works individually but not with how I want to read images.

Comment: Yes I can. I just edited my own answer as a response.

Comment: Thanks. I came across another solution (that I added in the qs). I don't really understand how the index work. Could you have a look?